# Excel macro skips step in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, macros

I want to make a simple macro that makes Pivot Table and then creates graph from it. When I insert the 'Date Occurance' in Axis Fields(row) in pivot table, macro has the step in its code, but does not run it when I run the macro. Graph is created without the 'Date Occurance' and when I check the Pivot Table, 'Date Occurance' is absent from required field.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date Occurred")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Specific Info 2")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Application Name")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fact that your macro code has "Date Occurred" and your field is actually titled "Date Occurrence".